# Go to next line in a file with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, twitter4j

I am trying to read lines from a file. For this, I am using the following code:

```
try {
    String line;
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("AbsoluteFilePath");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {
      FactGeneration.getFacts();
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        br.readLine();
        function1(line);
```

However, this does not move to the next line in the file.
Thank you!

Edit:
For clarity, I am making a twitter bot. The entire function looks like this:
FactGeneration.getFacts() appends a new line to the file located at /AbsoluteFilePath

```
private static void tweetLines() {
String tweet;
int count = 0;
while (count < 10) {
  try {
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
        "/AbsoluteFilePath");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {
      FactGeneration.getFacts();
      while ((tweet = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sendTweet(tweet);

        try {
          int sleepTime = 18000;
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  count += 1;
}
```

}

Edit:

The following is the working code:

```
while (count < numTweets) {
  try {
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {


      //Calls static method GetFacts from the FactGeneration class.
      FactGeneration.getFacts();
      tweet = br.readLine();
      while (tweet != null) {

        //sendTweet accesses the TwitterAPI and posts the tweet.
        sendTweet(tweet);
        System.out.println("tweeting:" + tweet);
        try {
          //Pauses the thread for the given amount of time.
          int sleepTime = 18000; //in milliseconds.
          System.out.printf("Sleeping for %d seconds", sleepTime / 1000);
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //moves to the next line in the file.
        tweet = br.readLine();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  count += 1;
  if (count == numTweets) {
    System.out.println("Tweet limit reached");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `readLine()` twice before displaying the line. Why?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I was just messing around with the code, trying to get it to work. Originally, I had only the single readLine(), in the header of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readLine` actually **reads** a line, it does it inside the condition of the `while` loop, so don't read a second time inside the loop

```
String line;
try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("AbsoluteFilePath");
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // do whatever with line

    }
}
```

---

The `while` condition has 2 steps, this allows, that at the end, it reads `null` and stop looping

- read a line from the file and assign the result to `line`
- check that `line` is not null

Comment: Even after changing it to using the single readLine(), it does not move to the next line.

Comment: @fragElephant so the problem it elsewhere, did you tried to just print the line ?

Comment: @fragElephant Please you may think about accepting an answer now or comment it ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the problem was with the placement of the readLine() in the code. I am updating the answer with the working code. Thank you!